# How To Prove This Is Continuous Or Discontinuous

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

How do I prove this is continuous/discontinuous?

A function $f(x)$ (can be any function, in general) is defined on the interval $[3,7]$, where $f(3)=2$ and $f(7)=4$. The range of $f(x)$ on this interval is $$2\leq f(x)\leq 4$$ for all $x \in [3,7]$.

$f$ has unique values on $[2,4]$ (so if $b$ is in $[2,4]$ there is only one $c$ in $[3,7]$ such that $f(c)=b$)

How should I prove that this is continuous/not continuous? I think using the intermediate value theory, we can assume that f(x) is continuous first and then use say that there is a point $c$ and  $$f(c) = \alpha$$ and $f(a) < \alpha < f(b)$. What do I do with the point next? The function $f(x)$ can be anything so I cannot use a single value for it. Please can someone help.

Comment: You cannot prove this function is continuous, nor it is discontinuous. There exist continuous and discontinuous functions satisfying these assumptions.

Answer (score -1):

If you can prove that for every alpha between f(a) and f(b) the function takes on a value, then you have proved the intermediate value theorem. In this cases, what I look for is a counter example. What you want is to look for all the f(c). That would be tedious. Just look for a counter example, such that f(d) = $\beta$ and $\beta$ does not lie in the interval between f(a) and f(b). If you cannot find such d, then from the intermediate value theorem, it is continuous.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it would be much appreciated if you can also tell me how I can find beta, because I do not have a specific function f(x).

Comment: You need to have a function, f(x) to get beta if beta exists. If beta exists, then it violates the theorem. Otherwise, it does not.